# Modal enclosed in screen react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal).

When I open screen 1, I have a button to open a modal. In this modal, there is a navigation button to navigate to screen 2.

This works, but the modal is not dismissed. Then navigation action happens **behind** the modal (I can see the animation through the backdrop). I want to navigate to screen 2 **on top of the modal**, and when I navigate back (`navigation.goBack()`), I want see the modal still open on screen 1.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the screenstack. Is there something I'm missing?

Screen 1 & 2:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default Screen1 = (props) => {
  const { navigate, goBack } = useNavigation();

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Screen1</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModal(true)}>
        <Text>Open modal</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Modal visible={modal}>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('Screen2')}>
            <Text>Go to screen 2</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Screen2 = (props) => {
  const { navigate, goBack } = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Screen2</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={goBack}>
        <Text>Back to screen 1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add function to take care of both navigating and dismissing the modal. Something like this should do the job

```
   const handleNavigation = () => {
    setModal(false);
    navigate('Screen2')
   }
```

and then call this function in your onPress method

```
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleNavigation()}>
        <Text>Go to screen 2</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not exactly what I want. When I navigate back, the modal is closed. I'm now trying ``react-native-modalbox``, this seems to be doing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal) will always render on top of your navigation because it has a separate activity and that activity will always render on top of the main activity, You have to close the modal to see the main activity behind, If you wanted to wanted the state of the previous screen while coming back you have to use [react-navigation-modal](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/)which will be a part of your navigator and will keep your state maintained.